# Simple Nokogiri not working: undefined method call for "Nokogiri"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, nomethoderror

I have Ruby and the Nokogiri gem installed. In irb, I try:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = 'http://www.amazon.com/The-Pragmatic-Programmer-Journeyman-Master/dp/020161622X/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1380758047&sr=8-1&keywords=the+programmatic+programmer'

data = Nokogiri::HTML::(open(url))

puts data
```

I always get the same error from the "data" variable.

```
NoMethodError: undefined method 'call' for Nokogiri:Module
  from (irb):5
  from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/irb:12:in '(main)'
```

I'm new with programming, so this may be something very obvious. Excuse my ignorance.

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect. Try: `Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))`

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Nokogiri::HTML.parse(open(url))
```

or

```
Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
```

Comment: Today, on first try the Nokogiri::HTML.parse(open(url)) worked. I tried the second and it worked also. I had been seeing that error over and over.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `call' for []:Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet
```

But for a different reason, in my case it was due to an extra dot (put by mistake) like this:

```
  status = data.css.("status font-large").text
```

Where it was fixed by removing the extra dot after the css as shown below

```
  status = data.css("status font-large").text
```

I hope this helps someone else